# arc via 3 points in specific direction

Tags: javascript, canvas, opengl-es, geometry

I need to draw the arc from 3 points in specific direction.

Lets say i have 3 vec2 points P1, P2, P3;

I've been manage to find arc center:

```
circleCenter: function (b, c, d) {
    var temp = Math.pow(c.x, 2) + Math.pow(c.y, 2);
    var bc = (Math.pow(b.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y, 2) - temp) / 2.;
    var cd = (temp - Math.pow(d.x, 2) - Math.pow(d.y, 2)) / 2.;
    var det = (b.x - c.x) * (c.y - d.y) - (c.x - d.x) * (b.y - c.y);

    if (Math.abs(det) < 1e-14)
        return false;

    var circ = new THREE.Vector2((bc * (c.y - d.y) - cd * (b.y - c.y)) / det,
    ((b.x - c.x) * cd - (c.x - d.x) * bc) / det
    );

    return circ;
},
```

and radius...

```
    var startPoint = P1;
    var endPoint = P3;
    var centerPoint = P2;

    var centerPoint = this.circle(startPoint, centerPoint, endPoint);

    var r = Math.sqrt((startPoint.x - centerPoint.x) * (startPoint.x - centerPoint.x) + (startPoint.y - centerPoint.y) * (startPoint.y - centerPoint.y));
```

third step is finding angles which is the place I've been stuck.
I'm calculating angles this way for each of point I have:

```
angleFromOrigin: function (c, p) {
    var x = p.x - c.x;
    var y = p.y - c.y;
    var theta = (180 / Math.PI * Math.atan2(y, x));
    return theta;
},
```

But this approach does not give me a) direction, b) it does not always include 3rd point (shows opposite arc on the circle)

so I need to correct those angles I have, using rotation direction (clockwise, counterclockwise) and 3rth angle i need to include in arc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh was there too while convert some specific vector data elliptic arcs to SVG ...

few if should do it. I see your case like this:

[image: arc]

try this angle correction:

```
if (a2-a1>+180.0) a2-=360.0;
if (a2-a1<-180.0) a2+=360.0;
if (a3-a2>+180.0) a3-=360.0;
if (a3-a2<-180.0) a3+=360.0;
```

and after this is direction easy:

```
if (a2-a1< 0) dir = CW;
if (a2-a1> 0) dir = CCW;
if (a2-a1==0) dir = none;
```

The only problem is when your arc cover whole 360 degree circle or more ...

- then this is not enough

draw can be done like this:

```
for (i=0,a=a1;i<100;i++,a+=(a3-a1)/99.0) // 100 lines per arc or use GDI arc ...
 {
 x=C.x + R*cos(a*PI/180.0);
 y=C.y + R*sin(a*PI/180.0); // or - R*...  if your render device has opposite Y direction
 if (!i) ...->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
 else    ...->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
 }
```

- R = |P1-C|

Comment: yes, your conversion pretty much helped alot... but still not there.

Comment: for ex: i have p1 and p3 in horisontal line....  p2 in the middle... when i'm moving it so p2.x becomes more then p3.x or less then p1.x, (no matter p2.y) it breaks up =( i'm getting wrong circle sector...
same when p1 and p3 in vertical.... and p2.y goes out of range....
anyway i guess, you gave me some acceleration out of the hole i've got in... at least i have direction to dig further...

Comment: in other words.... problem occures when angle between p1 and p3 more or eaquals 180.... and p2 is close to one of those points on the arc...

Comment: @user3732787 yes as I wrote in answer this works only if angle between any points is < 180 deg otherwise you need to add more info about your arc because it is not possible derive the info you need from points only. Also when you got 2 poits too close to each then your center computations loose precision so take that in mind too

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem, and it looks like you can calculate both direction and sweep angle by comparing the angles you've calculated.  If you have to go further back from the end angle to get to the start angle than to get to the middle angle, you're going clockwise.  You can regularize the angles for comparison by using the modulo operator (%), which solves the problem of crossing 360.  Something like this:

```
function determineDirection(start, middle, end) {
    endToStart = (end - start + 360) % 360;
    endToMiddle = (end - middle + 360) % 360;
    if (endToMiddle < endToStart) {
        return {direction: 'cw', sweepAngle: endToStart};
    } else {
        return {direction: 'ccw', sweepAngle: (360 - endToStart)};
    }
}

angleStart = angleFromOrigin(centerOfCircle, P1);
angleMiddle = angleFromOrigin(centerOfCircle, P2);
angleEnd = angleFromOrigin(centerOfCircle, P3);

direction = determineDirection(angleStart, angleMiddle, angleEnd);
```

Note that this function assumes that angles increase in the *clockwise* direction.  If you're using it for the typical case where angles increase in the *counterclockwise* direction, exchange the positions of 'cw' and 'ccw'.

Trying it out:

```
determineDirection(0, 1, 2)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 2}

determineDirection(2, 1, 0)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 2}

determineDirection(0, 2, 1)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(1, 2, 0)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(359, 0, 1)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 2}

determineDirection(359, 1, 0)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(0, 1, 359)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(1, 0, 359)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 2}

determineDirection(0, 359, 1)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(1, 359, 0)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 359}

determineDirection(0, 90, 180)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 180}

determineDirection(180, 90, 0)
> {direction: "ccw", sweepAngle: 180}

determineDirection(180, 0, 90)
> {direction: "cw", sweepAngle: 270}
```

I noticed that you're using "centerPoint" for both the center of the circle and the middle point in your arc, so I changed the variable names to avoid confusion.