# Circular Arc Through a Center Point

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I'm attempting to render an Arc through three specified points in OpenGL. Thus far I've managed to compute all of the different values required to do so (center and radius of the circle passing through the three points, and a start and end angle). My problem comes with deciding on the direction to draw the arc, clockwise or counter-clockwise, dependent on the location of the middle point. My code is as follows: (hacky experimental code, points[0] is start, points[1] is middle and points[2] is end)

```
void render()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// Circle Parameters
Point2D center = circleCenter(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
double circleRadius = radius(points[0], points[1], points[2]);

// Arc Parameters
double start = atan2(points[0].y - center.y, points[0].x - center.x) * (180 / M_PI);
double middle = atan2(points[1].y - center.y, points[1].x - center.x) * (180 / M_PI);
double end = atan2(points[2].y - center.y, points[2].x - center.x) * (180 / M_PI);

if (start < 0)
    start += 360;
if (middle < 0)
    middle += 360;
if (end < 0)
    end += 360;

// Render circle
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
{
    double degInRad = i * M_PI / 180;
    glVertex2d(cos(degInRad)*circleRadius + center.x, sin(degInRad)*circleRadius + center.y);
}
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

As you can see the arc is currently just being rendered between the start and end points. What would I need to do in order to ensure it renders in the correct direction, through the center point?

**Update 1:**
For example, in the below diagrams the blue points are my three defined points and the red is the circle center. In the top image, the arc passes through my middle point. But in the bottom image, the arc is still draw clockwise even though my middle point is now on the right. The same occurs for different start/end point combinations. Is there a uniform way to ensure the arc always passes through the center point?

Right:

[image: Right]

Wrong:

[image: Wrong]

Comment: Can you add an image of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not enough rep to add images, but I've linked some.

Comment: This mostly looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178416/arc-via-3-points-in-specific-direction. I can't mark it as a duplicate because the other question has no accepted/upvoted answer, but the content there should still be helpful.

Comment: Yep just use mine angle correction there ... and change MoveTo/LineTo with glVertex ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check where the middle lies.

```
(...)

if (end < start)
    end += 360;
if (middle < start)
    middle += 360;

if (middle < end)
  doNormal = true;
else 
  doNormal = false;

// Render circle
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (int i = doNormal ? start : end; i < doNormal ? end : start; i += doNormal ? 1 : -1)
   (...)
```